# How can I countunique with countifs?

Tags: google-sheets, countif, count-unique

I want to use count if, only if a value is unique.

I've tried a number of syntaxes starting with `countif` and `countunique`, but they all failed so far.

Here's one I've tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(COUNTUNIQUE('Copy of IMP CRM (for analysis)'!F:F),'Copy of IMP CRM (for analysis)'!I:I,"Phase 1 - Active")
```

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question is a bit ambiguous, but I think you may just want

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(filter(F:F,G:G="active"))
```